# The use of 'global' variables on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Ok, I went into a heated argument with a colleague about the way of properly using global variables on AngularJS. Here's his reasoning: there's many ways to "do" things.

Consider this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.globalVar = []; // this is just to store same data later
```

Then on some directive/service:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    app.globalVar = [23,43,21]; // populating from a json or other source
});

app.directive('myDirective2', function(){
    var x = app.globalVar;
});
```

I think this is bad but I would like to know, from a technical view, why this is wrong and what's the proper use of 'global' variables in AngularJS.

I read about using $rootScope and I also read somewhere that on version 2.0 AngularJS is dropping $scope altogheter so maybe the only way will be using a service/factory?

Comment: What is this global variable? Where it is used? How often value changes?...

Comment: Just a random variable to hold data for later use, nothing special. For example, it could be `var myArray = []` and then it would be used on various functions as a dumb variable that keeps changing values inside those functions. Hence the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I do not use global variables. They pollute the window scope and can make your code more confusing. For an example like the one you gave I would recommend using a factory or a service to persist the data. Then you can inject it clearly into whatever controller/direct/other-service that you want. While your co-worker is correct that there are many ways to do things I do not recommend polluting the global scope.

```
app.
 module('myApp')
 .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

function myFactory() {
  var globalVar = [23,43,21];

  return {
    get: function() {
      return globalVar;
    }
  }
}
```

and then in your controller(or whatever)

```
app.
  module('myApp')
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  function MyCtrl(myService) {
    var localVar = myService.get();
  }
```

Comment: What do you do when you want variables that supports $watch and use them in ng-model or any other way? I think its just fine to use $rootScope

Comment: Thanks @DannyBlue, I knew something wasn't right and your comment about the global scope added some positive insight on the argument with my colleague.

Comment: Yes @Ahmad, I suppose it is, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few conventions I follow while designing

a. **Global Variables**- Attach variables to `$rootscope` and then you can use that variables in any child `$scope`. Moreover, you can even listen to events on rootscope across controllers. **Tip**: Avoid this because you can end up with too many variables on `rootscope` and `listeners` spread across controllers.

b. **Angular Service**-  Use this when you want to share data between two or more controllers. This is most preferable way to access/share data.

c. **Angular Factory** - Very similar to Service but, use this to store static data such as base urls, api keys, button status between views etc.

d. **Angular Controller** - Try to keep your controllers with minimal coding and business logic. only, routing and basic binding should be done in controllers.

I hope it helps in your argument. :)

Answer (score 0):

Good way of using Global Variables

**Angular Service:**

```
(function () {

var userService = function () {

    var getGlobalVar = function () {
        var globalVar = [23, 43, 21];
    };
    return {
        globalVar: globalVar
    };
};
var mod = angular.module("myApp");
mod.factory("userService", userService);
}());
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
app.controller("MyCtrl",['userService' function (userService) {

var test = userService.getGlobalVar();
}]);
```